# How return empty resultset always from MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

I want to know How return empty resultset always from MySQL stored procedure, if there is any type error is raise on Procedure during data fetching.

Thanks

Comment: What type of error you are talking about?

Comment: do you use error handler in stored procedure ?

Comment: Any possible  error that can be raise through stored procdure, because procedure which i used, uses data from diffrent tables and do some calculation. if any data is not avilabel  in table it raisesMySQL error with some error code

Comment: Wait... so, you want to return an empty result set identical to the result set you would have returned if the procedure had succeeded? (?!) Same column definitions, but no rows?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your procedure, can use the `ERROR HANDLER`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure_namme`(OUT return_data TEXT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_error_code CHAR(5);
    DECLARE v_error_msg TEXT;    
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
         BEGIN
         GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
            v_error_code = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
            v_error_msg = message_text;
            SET return_data = NULL; -- IF ERROR OCCUR THEN ITS SET NULL
            SELECT v_error_code,v_error_msg;
         END
         -- BODY WHAT YOU WANT TO WRITE(LOGIC)

 END;
```

To know more about it you can refer this one
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-error-handling-in-stored-procedures/